# Adding active class :click

Tags: vue.js

I am having trouble adding an active class when clicking a link.

I have the dynamic class setup with a click listener that passes an argument to the function but the class does not update. I am not sure why. The 'Dashboard' link is red when page is refreshed so I know it is working to an extent.

```
<template>
  <b-list-group>
    <b-list-group-item
      v-for="(link, index) in menu"
      :key="index"
      :href="link.sectionId"
      :class="{active: link.title === selectedLink}"
      :click="isActive(link.title)"
    >
      {{link.title}}
    </b-list-group-item>
  </b-list-group>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedLink: 'Dashboard',
      menu: [
        {
          title: 'Dashboard',
          icon: labStuffs,
          sectionId: '#'
        },
        {
          title: 'Lactose intolerance',
          icon: labStuffs,
          sectionId: '#'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isActive(title) {
      this.selectedLink === title
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

Expecting the background colour of clicked link to change. Only the dashboard link is red and whenever I click anything else, nothing happens.

Comment: Shouldn't `this.selectedLink === title` in your method be `this.selectedLink = title` instead?

Comment: I get a console warning saying there is an infinite loop

Comment: Oh, you have both an href and a click event on the `b-list-group-item` which renders as an anchor tag in the html. Might want to handle route change and active class in the same logic? Also, shoudn't it be `@click` instead of `:click`

Comment: Nice idea @BrandonFranklin however even without the href it is still not changing the background colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of your code.

I changed the :click to @click and the following.

```
methods: {
    isActive(title) {
      this.selectedLink = title // Had === before
    }
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-y3k12?fontsize=14

Comment: Thank you so much!